Setbounds for Mapbox GL JS in Albers
Are there any ways to set the initial bounds for a Mapbox GL JS map when the projection is in Albers? Example below
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  projection: "albers",
  center: [-74.5, 40],
  zoom: 9,
  bounds: [-78, 44, -91, 39]
});

There are many issues listed on github where this problem is referenced.
Here's a working example with default projection
https://codepen.io/dogcats/pen/mdZQBrq
Here changing the projection to Albers demonstrates the issue.
https://codepen.io/dogcats/pen/QWXJqGY
